# Arquivo .bat não executa

Tags: windows, servidor, cmd

Tenho um arquivo com o seguinte comando para desligar algumas máquinas da rede.

```
FOR /F %i IN (C:\estacoes.txt) DO SHUTDOWN /s /t 01 /m %i
```

Onde estacoes.txt é um arquivo com os nomes das máquinas a serem desligadas.

Quando eu abro o cmd e executo esse comando na mão ele funciona corretamente. Porém quando eu salvo num arquivo .bat e tento executar ele não executa.

Tentei executar como administrador e também não funcionou.

Comment: Coloca um `PAUSE` no final do documento e então poderá olhar os erros que ocorrem.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz desta maneira e funcionou

```
echo off
cls
for /F %%i in (%homedrive%\estacoes.txt) do (
SHUTDOWN /s /t 01 /m %%i
)
```

Exemplo da lista que eu fiz:

```
windowsxp
portaria
novowindows
```

Testei em um Windows x64 (Windows 8.1) para desligar outras máquinas e depois diretamente e no final ela própria, depois testei em uma máquina x32 (Windows XP SP2), também foi corretamente.

Só não pude desligar a máquina com Windows 8.1 por que precisa autenticar por um usuário dela.

Se você usar *ping* pode verificar se a máquina está ligada ou conectada a rede antes de tentar desligar, isso evita a espera longa e desnecessária do `FOR`.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe do `FOR` para um comando de única linha se dirige apenas para quando irá usar o Console diretamente, para um arquivo BATCH não é necessário a diretiva `/F`.

```
@echo off
FOR %%i IN (C:\estacoes.txt) DO SHUTDOWN /s /t 01 /m %%i
pause
```

Além disso, terá de usar o `%%i` ao invés de `%i`.

> Obs.: Remova o `pause` no final da linha se não for depurar este código.

Comment: Alterei o comando para o jeito que você falou mas mesmo assim não funciona. Deixei com o pause para ver se depurava, porém ao executar o arquivo ele tenta abrir o prompt, fica menos de 1s aberto e já fecha e não executa a tarefa. Estou usando o windows 10

Comment: Estranho, aqui funcionou corretamente. Windows 8.1.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, abre o CMD, pegue o .bat e arraste-o no CMD e solte. Conte para gente o que vai aparecer.

Comment: Bom dia. Fiz isso. Apenas apareceu o nome do aquivo e mais nada. Att, Maurício.

Comment: Provavelmente é questão de segurança, ou seja, precisa autenticar antes de enviar o comando, qual a versão do Windows de cada máquina?

Answer (score 0):

---

- Para evitar erros, você pode ir verificando se a estação está UP (sugestão do [@OldSchool](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/104928/oldschool)), isso antes de enviar o comando para desligar, outra coisa importante, seria emitir algum aviso ao usuário para evitar a perda de trabalho.

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

color 0A && title ..\%~dpnx0 && mode 100,10  && chcp 1252 >nul 

for /f %%i IN (C:\estacoes.txt)do "%__APPDIR__%ping.exe" %%~i -n 2 -4 >nul && (
"%__APPDIR__%ShutDown.exe" /m \\%%~i /s /f /d p:1:2 /c "Salve seus trabalhos, Estação será desligada em 300 segundos!!" /t 300 2>nul
) || ( Echo/ & echo/ Estação %%~i nao responde Pings ou o Agendamento de Desligamento jah esta em curso) 

endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

> - Igualmente citado nessa resposta **[Q426377](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426243/acesso-negado-para-acesso-remoto-via-wmi/426377#426377)** **-** Praticamente é o mesmo **tema/resposta**

O acesso remoto tem que estar habilitado na estação por uma configuração que feita localmente, não basta apenas enviar uma solicitação de acesso e/ou um comando, as outras estações onde (noutro domínio ou não) o seu comando tem funcionado, é resultado de uma configuração aplicada quando foi necessário anteriormente.

Essa restrição veio por padrão desde o Windows Vista, permitindo acesso remoto (filtrado) para apenas usuários membros do grupo administrador **local**.

Via **[prompt](/questions/tagged/prompt)** execute um **`reg query`** na chave abaixo e verifique se lhe retorna:

**`EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1`**       ***ou***        **`EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x0`**

---

```bat
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" | findstr "EnableLUA"
Rem :: EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1

rem ::  Então adicione a entrada/valor 0
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

---

Resumindo:

Verificar na estação de destino, se existe essa chave e se está habilitada(0x1):

---

```bat
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system" | find "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" | find "0x1"
```

Se ela existir e estiver habilitada, o comando lhe retorna:

---

```bat
LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

Para o caso não existir ou o valor difere de 0x1, use esse comando para adicionar/habilitar:

---

```bat
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system" /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

---