# Acesso negado para acesso remoto via WMI

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

Olá!

Estou tentando realizar um acesso remoto via WMI em um servidor com domínio diferente da minha maquina, porém quando tento realizar o acesso o seguinte código é retornado: Acesso negado. (0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Alguém consegue me auxiliar?

Lembrando que existem outros servidores no mesmo domínio que eu e neles consigo realizar o acesso remoto normalmente.

Segue o código:

```
public class Serviços
{
    Coleções.Serviços _serviçosCol;
    Objetos.Serviço _serviçoObj;

    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[] _serviçosSC;

    public Coleções.Serviços Carregar(string ip, string login, string senha)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Password = senha;
            options.Username = login;
            options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Connect;
            options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Identify;

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + ip + "\\root\\cimv2", options);
            scope.Connect();

            _serviçosCol = new Coleções.Serviços();
            _serviçosSC = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices(ip);

            for (int i = 0; i < _serviçosSC.Length; i++)
            {
                _serviçoObj = new Objetos.Serviço();
                _serviçoObj.Nome = _serviçosSC[i].ServiceName;
                _serviçoObj.Status = _serviçosSC[i].Status.ToString();

                _serviçosCol.Adicionar(_serviçoObj);
            }

            return _serviçosCol;
        }
        catch (Exception _erro)
        {
            throw _erro;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

O acesso remoto tem que estar habilitado na estação por uma configuração que feita localmente, não basta apenas enviar uma solicitação de acesso e/ou um comando, as outras estações onde (noutro domínio ou não) o seu comando tem funcionado, é resultado de uma configuração aplicada quando foi necessário anteriormente.

Essa restrição veio por padrão desde o Windows Vista, permitindo acesso remoto (filtrado) para apenas usuários membros do grupo administrador **local**.

Via **[prompt](/questions/tagged/prompt)** execute um **`reg query`** na chave abaixo e verifique se lhe retorna:

**`EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1`**       ***ou***        **`EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x0`**

---

```bat
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" | findstr "EnableLUA"
Rem :: EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1
 
rem ::  Então adicione a entrada/valor 0
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

---

Resumindo:

Verificar na estação de destino, se existe essa chave e se está habilitada(0x1):

```bat
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system" | find "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" | find "0x1"
```

Se ela existir e estiver habilitada, o comando lhe retorna:

```bat
LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

Para o caso não existir ou o valor difere de 0x1, use esse comando para adicionar/habilitar:

```bat
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system" /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

---

Se ainda assim não funcionar, tente seguir esse how to:

> [enable remote wmi access for a domain user account:](https://gsx.com/resources/sharepoint/enable-remote-wmi-access-for-a-domain-user-account/) /en
>
> [permitir o acesso remoto WMI para uma conta de usuário de domínio:](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=en&tl=pt&u=https%3A%2F%2Fgsx.com%2Fresources%2Fsharepoint%2Fenable-remote-wmi-access-for-a-domain-user-account%2F&sandbox=1) /pt **tradução Google**